# Перебор массива в php

Tags: php

Есть массив, как его правильно перебрать?Пробовал с помощью

```
foreach ($string as $value){
        echo $value;
    }
```

Не получается

```
   $string = [
        {
        "id": "1",
        "children": [],
        "text": "Понедельник",
        "level": null,
        "data": {},
        "type": "video"
        },
        {
        "id": "2",
        "children": [],
        "text": "Вторник",
        "level": null,
        "data": {},
        "type": "video"
        },
        {
        "id": "3",
        "children": [],
        "text": "Среда",
        "level": null,
        "data": {},
        "type": "video"
        },
        {
        "id": "1",
        "children": [],
        "text": "Пятница",
        "level": null,
        "data": {},
        "type": "video"
        }
        ]
```

Comment: `“”` не являются корректным синтаксисом в PHP. Используйте `"`. А так - да, через `foreach` можно перебирать массивы.

Comment: Все равно не работает, к сожалению

Comment: Вы присвоили массив формата JSON к переменной php (как строку) как вы хотите его перебрать? ))) Если так делать то присваивайте `$array = json_decode('$string');` и уже потом перебирайте массив `$array`

Comment: Хм, но при ajax запросе, в консоли,data выводит как массив,странно ведь

Comment: Если вы копировали строку с консоли, там он показывает массив данных переданный php скрипту в JSON формате. А как вы передаете эти данные php скрипту? Интересуют 2 строки в аяксе = `type:` и `data:`

Comment: `$string = file_get_contents('./data_php.json');
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 echo $string;`

Comment: `$array = json_decode('$string');` - только что попробовал, тоже не работает, к сожалению

Comment: `type:'get'` . data нету

Comment: `var_dump($string);` пожалуйста, точней маленький кусочек в начале   (если строка будет длинной)

Comment: Да. вы правы, не массив, переменная - строка `string(160582) `

Comment: Но, при ` $array = json_decode('$string');`  - NULL

Comment: `json_decode` преобразовал бы строку `$string` как в вашем примере в массив php, но т.к. через функцию `file_get_contents` вы получили `string(160582)`, естественно ничего путнего не произойдет )

Comment: И как тогда быть? Json  у меня в отдельном файле, как же без `file_get_contents`

Comment: Запрос вы вроде стоите правильно, вам следует проверить json файл и еще раз обратиться к инструкции в виде [этой](https://ploshadka.net/json-to-php/), но получение массива из json файла это уже другой вопрос )))

Comment: Ага, проверил на ошибки, собственно выдает JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX, как-то так

Comment: @Litrein, если вы действительно используете такой код `$array = json_decode('$string');` по совету RifmaMan, то вы зря это делаете. Тут функция обрабатывает не содержимое переменной `$string`, а строку `$string` ;)

Comment: @Visman Согласен, ошибся ) `$array = json_decode($string);`

Comment: Спасибо большое, сделал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вероятно получаете где-то `JSON` строку, и пытаетесь сразу именно ее перебрать, но это не верное, сначала сделайте из строки строку, таким образом.

```
$string = '[
    {
    "id": "1",
    "children": [],
    "text": "Понедельник",
    "level": null,
    "data": {},
    "type": "video"
    },
    {
    "id": "2",
    "children": [],
    "text": "Вторник",
    "level": null,
    "data": {},
    "type": "video"
    },
    {
    "id": "3",
    "children": [],
    "text": "Среда",
    "level": null,
    "data": {},
    "type": "video"
    },
    {
    "id": "1",
    "children": [],
    "text": "Пятница",
    "level": null,
    "data": {},
    "type": "video"
    }
    ]'
```

Далее преобразуйте `JSON` строку в массив

```
$arr = json_decode($string, true);
```

А потом перебирайте

```
foreach ($arr as $value){
    print_r($value);
}
```